# WordPress PHP - Hyperlink on image

Tags: php, html, wordpress

first sorry if this is a simple question, its my first time with html / word press and this is just a learning exercise

basically i have downloaded the lawyeria lite theme on word-press, and in this theme they have three icons on the homepage with text underneath them , and what i want to do is make it so a user can click on the image and gets taken to another page, however in the customization options of the theme this is not possible.

i think i have found the php related for this, below, my question is how can i modify this to achieve my aim ?

```
                    <?php
                        if ( get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_icon',get_template_directory_uri().'/images/features-box-icon-one.png' ) ) { 

                            echo '<div class="features-box-icon">';


                                echo '<img src="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_icon', get_template_directory_uri().'/images/features-box-icon-one.png' ).'" alt="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_title' ).'" title="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_title' ).'" ;/>';

                            echo '</div>';
                        }

                        if ( get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_title','Lorem' ) ) {

                            echo '<h4>';

                                echo get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_title','Lorem' );

                            echo '</h4>';   
                        }

                        if ( get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_content','Go to Appearance - Customize, to add content.' ) ) {

                            echo '<p>';

                                echo get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_content','Go to Appearance - Customize, to add content.' );

                            echo '</p>';    
                        }
                    ?>
            </div><!--/div .features-box-->
```

and i have narrowed it down to this line of code :

```
                                echo '<img src="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_secondlybox_icon',get_template_directory_uri().'/images/features-box-icon-two.png' ).'" alt="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_secondlybox_title','Ipsum' ).'" title="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_secondlybox_title','Ipsum' ).'" />';
```

i have tried adding in a href

```
echo '< href="page.php" 'img src="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_secondlybox_icon',get_template_directory_uri().'/images/features-box-icon-two.png' ).'" alt="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_secondlybox_title','Ipsum' ).'" title="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_secondlybox_title','Ipsum' ).'" />';
```

---

but this give a HTTP ERROR 500

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like i was on the right track but wrong format, this is how i have achieved what i wanted

```
echo '<a href="pageone.php"><img src="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_icon', get_template_directory_uri().'/images/features-box-icon-one.png' ).'" alt="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_title' ).'" title="'.get_theme_mod( 'lawyeria_lite_frontpage_firstlybox_title' ).'" ;/></a>';
```